# Opening a new mail in the Mail client with a joined pdf Java

Tags: java, email, javafx, desktop

my question is about the Desktop API (Desktop.Action.MAIL ) for Java I want to use it to open a new mail with the default mail client with a joined pdf file, I use this code to open a new mail with subject and To fields filled.

```
@FXML
private void sending_mail(ActionEvent event) throws URISyntaxException,IOException 
{
    Desktop desktop;
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported() && (desktop = Desktop.getDesktop()).isSupported(Desktop.Action.MAIL)) 
    {
        URI mailto = new URI("mailto:example@example.com? subject=Hello%20World");
        desktop.mail(mailto);
    } 
    else 
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("desktop doesn't support mailto)");
    }
}
```